# Grafana dashboard for Kubernetes with separate simple view for each pod and their resource limits

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus

I want to know if there is any ready to use OR how I can create a grafana dashboard with below specifications:

I want a dashboard that shows each pod as a cube or circle or any shape. If the pod is using like 80% of its resource limit (cpu/memory) the color of that shape changes from green to red.

I have to mention that I have a Prometheus + grafana in place and I am using them and I just need to know how to create such a dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grafana includes a panel type called [Single Stat Panel](https://grafana.com/docs/features/panels/singlestat/) which should do what you need. It can be set to change background or text colour based on thresholds you determine, so if you have an output metric which is a percentage, you can specify what percentage to change at. It does 2 stage changes, so you can use traffic lights to indicate a warning before a metric gets to emergency levels.

If you have multiple similar metrics you want to create panels for, you can use Grafana's [templating variables](https://grafana.com/docs/reference/templating/) to get a list of unique pod identifiers (depending on what labels are available to you), and then use the [repeat panel](https://grafana.com/docs/reference/templating/#repeating-panels) option to automatically create one panel per pod. WARNING: if you have a huge number of pods, this option could stall or crash your browser! If you think this will be a problem then I recommend making one dashboard with all the metrics for a single pod, and using a variable to switch between them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I think something like https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/vonage-status-panel is more in line with what I was looking for (I haven't implemented it because something else came up). Just one question, how many pods will be considered too much? My platform consists of around 20 components and each can also scale so we are talking about something around 20-50 pods, is this too much for the browser?

Comment: Ah no, 20-50 should be fine. The issue isn't a specific number of pods, but how much memory your browser ends up consuming trying to load all the metric data and display the whole dashboard. A user I was helping tried to do this for ~700 servers and it was a very bad experience!

Answer (score 0):

I installed the steps, hope can help you.
[kubernetes_prometheus_monitor](https://github.com/bbotte/kube-prometheus/blob/master/manifests/kubernetes_prometheus_monitor.md)

if you just monitoring pod, simple with cadvisor

[linux工匠之docker和kubernetes的监控(cadvisor+prometheus)](http://www.bbotte.com/monitor-safe/docker-monitor-with-cadvisor-and-prometheus/)